# Custom view frame is set differently

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I created a custom view: **CustomComponent** In these custom view, I have a collection view and collection view cells. Here is the code for it:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "PastMonthCollectionViewCell.h"
#import "CurrentMonthCollectionViewCell.h"
#import "FutureMonthCollectionViewCell.h"
#import "HighlightedMonthCollectionViewCell.h"

@interface CustomComponent : UIView<UICollectionViewDelegate,UICollectionViewDataSource,UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout>
@property (nonatomic, strong) UICollectionView* collectionView;
@property (nonatomic, strong) HighlightedMonthCollectionViewCell * highlightedMonthCollectionViewCell;
@property (nonatomic, strong) PastMonthCollectionViewCell * pastMonthViewCollectionViewCell;
@property (nonatomic, strong) CurrentMonthCollectionViewCell * currentMonthViewCollectionViewCell;
@property (nonatomic, strong) FutureMonthCollectionViewCell * futureMonthViewCollectionViewCell;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSDate* birthDate;
@property  CGFloat minimumSpaceBetweenCells;
@property int numberOfMonths;
@property int targetIndex;
```

@end

When I take a generic UIView and drag it out the Main.storyboard, my CustomView's frame comes as (0,0,240,128). However, in the storyboard I arranged its constraints as follows:
[image]

Strange thing is, its height is specified as 100 and its margins are 0 from left and 0 from right. However when the application runs, it is:
[image]

There is a huge space after black area. 
In summary, Problem is: Why did custom view's frame is set differently?

Thanks :)

Comment: Is it possible that the view has the correct size, but the elements inside the view are not scaled?

Comment: I gave their size properly.